# Alias not recognised in subquery case statement SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause, alias

I have the following query that runs fine when the Where isn't populated but I'm having difficulty getting the right references for the data in the where.

Code is below:

```
SELECT g.Id as Id,                                                                                               
       g.Printed as Printed,
       g.CreatedDate as CreatedDate , 

       case when (                            
           Select Count(Distinct custSubGA.CustomerId) from PickingAssignment_PickingAssignmentUserGroup custSubG 
              join PickingAssignment custSubGA on custSubGA.Id = custSubG.PickingAssignmentId
                      join Customer custSub2C on custSubGA.CustomerId = custSub2C.Id
                            where custSubG.PickingAssignmentUserGroupId = Max(g.Id)
                    ) > 1 
                    then 'Multiple' 
       else (
           Select Max(custSub2C.Name) from PickingAssignment_PickingAssignmentUserGroup custSub2G 
               join PickingAssignment custSub2GA on custSub2G.PickingAssignmentId = custSub2GA.Id                               
               join Customer custSub2C on custSub2GA.CustomerId = custSub2C.Id
               where custSub2G.PickingAssignmentUserGroupId = Max(g.Id) 
       ) end  as CustomerName 

from PickingAssignmentUserGroup g  
where   CustomerName like 'exet%'
```

I also tried using " where custSub2C.Name like 'exet%' and that didn't work either. The multi-part identifier custSub2C.Name could not be bound is what I get from that.

This is the first time I've attempted case statements in SQL so there's a chance I'm doing it very very wrong.

Any help would be fantastic. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` statement at the same level.  In most databases, you would just use a subquery:

```
select *
from (SELECT g.Id as Id, g.Printed as Printed, g.CreatedDate as CreatedDate , 
             case when (Select Count(Distinct custSubGA.CustomerId)
                        from PickingAssignment_PickingAssignmentUserGroup custSubG join
                             PickingAssignment custSubGA
                             on custSubGA.Id = custSubG.PickingAssignmentId join
                             Customer custSub2C
                             on custSubGA.CustomerId = custSub2C.Id
                        where custSubG.PickingAssignmentUserGroupId = Max(g.Id)
                    ) > 1 
                    then 'Multiple' 
                  else (Select Max(custSub2C.Name)
                        from PickingAssignment_PickingAssignmentUserGroup custSub2G join 
                             PickingAssignment custSub2GA
                             on custSub2G.PickingAssignmentId = custSub2GA.Id join                           
                             Customer custSub2C
                             on custSub2GA.CustomerId = custSub2C.Id
                        where custSub2G.PickingAssignmentUserGroupId = Max(g.Id) 
                       )
             end  as CustomerName
      from PickingAssignmentUserGroup g  
     ) t
where   CustomerName like 'exet%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon already pointed out, the column alias are resolved after the `WHERE`, but is also possible to move the subqueries in the `CASE` to the `FROM` and, as the only difference is the field in the `SELECT`, merge them.

```
SELECT g.Id as Id,
       g.Printed as Printed,
       g.CreatedDate as CreatedDate , 

       CASE WHEN CM.CustomerCount > 1 THEN 'Multiple' 
            ELSE CM.Name 
       END as CustomerName

FROM   PickingAssignmentUserGroup g
       OUTER APPLY (
             SELECT Max(custSub2C.Name) Name
                  , Count(Distinct custSubGA.CustomerId) CustomerCount
             FROM   PickingAssignment_PickingAssignmentUserGroup custSub2G 
                    INNER JOIN PickingAssignment custSub2GA 
                       ON custSub2G.PickingAssignmentId = custSub2GA.Id
                    INNER JOIN Customer custSub2C 
                       ON custSub2GA.CustomerId = custSub2C.Id
             WHERE  custSub2G.PickingAssignmentUserGroupId = Max(g.Id)) CM
WHERE  CM.Name like 'exet%' AND CM.CustomerCount = 1
```